# How to Mongo query for only fields entered in Search Form?

Tags: mongodb, search, express, mongodb-query, mean-stack

I have a search form that acts as a filter. I want only the fields that have something entered to be used for the Mongo query.

This is my backend Routes.js. If the user did not enter anything for seat_price_static, then this .find() should not try to match the $and on both parameters.

```
// Routes.js from backend
app.get('/search', function(req, res, next){
   Trip.find({
         $and: [
              {seats_remaining: {$gte: req.query.seats_remaining}},
              {seat_price_static: {$lte: req.query.seat_price_static}}
         ]
   }, function(err, trips){
         if(err){return next(err)};
         return res.json(trips);
   });
});
```

How can I setup this flexibility?

//===================================================================//
//================== SOME EXTRA INFO IF NEEDED ======================//

This is my frontend search fields. If only seats_remaining is entered, then I want the Mongo query to ignore the seat_price_static field.

```
// searchForm.html
<input type='number' ng-model='search.seats_remaining'>
<input type='number' ng-model='search.seat_price_static'>
<button ng-click='searchIt(search)'>Search</button>
```

And here is my client-side Controller.js. As you can see, it sends the `search` object to the backend.

```
// Controller.js from front-end client
App.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http){
   $scope.searchIt = function(search){
      $http.get('http://localhost:3000/search', {params: search})
          .then(function(data){
              console.log('Got the search results ' + data);
          }, function(err){
              console.log(err);
          });
   }
};
```

I am using MEAN stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `$and` for this. Whatever comma separated key Value pairs you give in the query document are implicitly **ANDed**

Now for your case, what you can do is create a query document. After that, check if `req.query` contains seats_remaining and seat_price_static values. If it does, add them to the query document.

If not leave them. Something like this :

```
var query = {};

if(req.query.seats_remaining) query.seats_remaining = {$gte: {req.query.seats_remaining }};
```

Do the same for req.query seat_price_static.

And then :

```
Trip.find(query, function(err, trips){ //your code to handle the response from MongoDB  })
```

Hope this helps.